# Running Autohotkey in the background

Tags: background

~CapsLock::Suspend
LButton::
Sleep 25
Click
Sleep 14
Send {3 Down}
Sleep 14
Send {3 Up}
Sleep 14
Send {q Down}
Sleep 14
Send {q up}
return

can you guys pls help me run these codes while in a fullscreen playing a game. 
game name: PBlackout.exe

Comment: Are you asking how to send the script output to a background window, or are you saying when you use the hotkeys in your game, nothing is happening?  I'm assuming you are saying there is no response from the game, so I will post an answer regarding that.

Answer (score 0):

### Keys not working in game

---

If what you are saying is that while in your game, your hotkeys aren't working, this is usually an easy fix.

When you are about to start your script, right click on the file and select:

```
Run as administrator
```

---

### Keys are not sending to background window

---

If the issue is that you want your shortcuts to be sent to a window other than the game you are running in FulLScreen, use the ControlSend command (http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/ControlSend.htm) and the ControlClick command (http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/ControlClick.htm)

For example:

```
;ControlSend [, Control, Keys, WinTitle, WinText, ExcludeTitle, ExcludeText]
;ControlClick [, Control-or-Pos, WinTitle, WinText, WhichButton, ClickCount, Options, ExcludeTitle, ExcludeText]

~CapsLock::Suspend 

LButton:: 
Sleep 25
ControlClick, SomeXCoordinates SomeYCoordinates, TitleOfBackgroundWindow
Sleep 14 
ControlSend,, {3 Down}, TitleOfBackgroundWindow
Sleep 14
ControlSend,, {3 Up}, TitleOfBackgroundWindow
Sleep 14
ControlSend,, {q Down}, TitleOfBackgroundWindow
Sleep 14 
ControlSend,, {q Up}, TitleOfBackgroundWindow
return
```